# Why initialisation is in the different order in similar code snippets. Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, storyboard

Why this snippets works differently:

1 - works fine

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var fullName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!

    var viewModel: TableViewCellViewModelType? {
        willSet(viewModel) {
            fullName.text = viewModel?.fullName
            age.text = viewModel?.age
        }
    }
}
```

2 - Error, because label equals nil. But this snippet works well if I remove willSet block and use viewWillAppear instead

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var viewModel: DetailViewModelType? {
        willSet(viewModel) {
            guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
            self.label.text = viewModel.description
        }
    }
}
```

Why for the first case everything works fine and all outlets are not nil and the second case works another way and outlet is nil at the moment viewModel is set (from the prepareForSegue method of the source VC)

Answer (score 0):

The second case label is nil because the VC is not yet presented so all it's outlets are nil (in contrast in `viewWillAppear` ) , but it works with the cell as it's already being loaded

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why when I set breakpoints first breakpoint that fired is outlet then willSet one. If so should be vise versa, right? or I miss something?